# Why is using isampler2D causing my shader to fail to compile in WebGL2?

Tags: webgl2

I have a fragment shader which is failing to compile in a WebGL 2 context:

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform isampler2D tex_in;
out vec2 outColor;
void main() {
    outColor = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
}
```

When I `gl.compileShader` this shader, `gl.getShaderParameter(glFragmentShader, GL.COMPILE_STATUS)` returns `false`. If I change `isampler2D` to `sampler2D`, the compile succeeds instead.

According to the [webgl 2 quick reference](https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl20-reference-guide.pdf), `isampler2D` is a supported keyword. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a precision for the sampler:

```
uniform highp isampler2D tex_in;
```

Note the `highp`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just point out the specific issue it's just a good practice to print the shader log when `gl.getShaderParameter(shader, GL.COMPILE_STATUS)` is `false`

example

```js
const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
const s = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(s, `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform isampler2D tex_in;
out vec2 outColor;
void main() {
    outColor = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
}`);
gl.compileShader(s);
if (!gl.getShaderParameter(s, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
  throw new Error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(s));
}
```

prints

```
Uncaught Error: ERROR: 0:3: 'isampler2D' : No precision specified
```

So the issue is you didn't specify a precision